# Best way to install fixed bathroom shelves

Tags: bathroom, adhesive, shelving, bathroom-fixtures

My contractor had installed 4 bathroom shelves but three of them have fallen down. These I guess require glue. Is that the problem?

Is there another way to install them so like with screws so it will never fall?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I cannot imagine how any "glue" that would hold those. But then again, you may want to inquire your local big box or hardware store and ask. Gluing right directly to polished to polished ceramic / porcelain tiles doesn't seem feasible as a practice. I would imagine if that there *WAS* a way to glue these like this, the *surface to surface* would *have to be* unpolished and / or ROUGH ( with small peaks & valleys prepped) to get a good bond design for surface grip strength... The other route would be either porcelain / ceramic "L" brackets or of the stainless steel type.. In which case you're going to need a special drill bit to mount them...
Here's one type:

See below image / link
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Dolle-FLAC-Stainless-Steel-Metal-Shelf-Bracket-for-1-4-in-5-16-in-H-Shelves-15750/204640318?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CD59%7CMulti%7CNA%7CLIA%7CAll_Storage_LIA|71700000048022671|58700004795392476|92700041080510599&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=CjwKCAjwkqPrBRA3EiwAKdtwk7j0A5TjHlsAAHyqs0uK06bJ6-HzDzd1PDt7Bi6BJtSYg_Ylrow0ZxoCTPAQAvD_BwE

Comment: Apparently these shelves don't have any other mechanism (bought them for lowes) but thanks for link, I think that might be the right way to install them. But do you know if I pre-drill a hole in the tile and install this? Don't want the title to crack!

Comment: Yes. Ask for the very best tile drill possible. There's YouTube videos of "how to drill through tile" and watch those... There's some really good ones so you'll have something to reference to. Best wishes for your shelving install

Answer (score 3):

Usually those shelves are mounted to the wall structure behind the tiles, most often into one or two studs.

You need to find the studs and then drill into them for proper support.

While you **should** get the contractor back to sort poor work, I would hesitate as they may not know any better...

Often those shelves are mounted first then the tiles are cut to surround the shelf.

Comment: I thought that's how they used to installed in old times, particularly even towel rods and toilet paper holders. Those were incredible hard to remove & replace. Now those things are installed with screws and anchors but I don't see any mechanism that these shelves can support.

Comment: It is. But in this day and age, everything's more focused on less labor intensive installs. For years they've had *tile look* shower walls with shelves built into them. All plastic injection molded stuff. Looks beautiful, and that is what most people care about.

Comment: @zar you asked for other ways to install... you did not exclude any or “old” methods...